# Access denied to lookup column in workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, permissions

I have 2 subsites in a SharePoint 2013 farm, at the same level in the same site collection. Workflow was created in site A as a test before recreating in site B (live). The workflow sets a variable to a lookup column ID and creates new entries in multiple lists within the respective site.

The workflow works flawlessly in Site A, but in Site B, only the site owner/admin can successfully run the workflow. All other users get a HTTP Unauthorized error referencing the lookup column.

I have checked that the permissions, lists, and workflows are identical on both subsites.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy the workflow? If yes, can you remove the step which assigns the value to the variable and re create the step again at the same place as earlier and try publish and verify?

Comment: I didn't copy the workflow, I recreated it in the new site. Thanks for the thought though.